# Failed audit on deleted answer with "no action needed" - bit unfair?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Just did a Late Answer review, which turned out to be an audit, which I failed.

I know we're supposed to review question/answer as it appears in the review queue, but I prefer to do what's best for the site, and my time, and there is no action required on something which does not exist!

I think "no action needed" should be acceptable when:

1. Answer or question is deleted

AND

2. Reviewer has clicked "link to question"

Obviously an attempt has been made to evaluate, and is now known answer or question doesn't exist.

Or if you really want to make sure people are doing a bit of work, perhaps add a button "This answer/question has been deleted". Which will be something we need to investigate before using (and also removes chance of people clicking any old button hoping to get it right - rep hungry etc).

---

The answer:

> Where is your JavaScript code?
>
> P.S. You can use AJAX for this. [See this question answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable) For
>   example, you can use dataType option of jQuery .get() (or .ajax())

This was the question where the reviewed answer was posted:
[load some content from txt and add to html markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015924/load-some-content-from-txt-and-add-to-html-markup)

I clicked the link to view the question to see if it was adequate - sometimes a single sentence is enough, however I could see the answer wasn't there.

I looked back at the answer in the review, and thought it might be an audit, but also thought perhaps in the time I looked at the review and read the answer, it had been deleted by the user (perhaps following downvotes, as should happen).

Either way, even if the answer was *spam, poor, rude, wrong, not an answer, whatever* - it had been removed. So my evaluating the whole situation deemed that, instead of downvoting, or flagging as "poor quality", there was no point as there was no answer to perform such actions with! So "no action needed"!

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention.

I was, the answer was no longer on the question "so no action needed".

> This answer was of very poor quality, and needed significant improvements to be useful

Determined by what criteria? Significant? The answer wasn't very good admittedly, but wasn't *terrible*. It did attempt to answer, and linked to another Stack answer, which would have helped the OP.

This would have needed nothing more than downvoting, but logically why would I downvote an answer which is not longer there?

> passing over such posts hurts the ability of others to find and answer good questions.

How? It was deleted!

> Please try to fix such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very low quality".

Why? It was deleted!

> We've already handled this post appropriately

I know, it was deleted, so "no action needed".

The review asked me:
"This question is a bit late to the party, can you see if it's ok please?"
I replied
"Yes, I've had a looksie, and you were right, it wasn't very good, but it's been removed, so (ahem) no action is needed...".

Should this be incorporated into the audit scripts so "no action needed" is acceptable when answer/question is deleted and reviewer has clicked "link to question"?

Comment: If you see a bad post in the review queue, you should choose a negative action on the post. That's a rule. Similar to: if you see red traffic light, you should stop the car.  The rule does not become void if you know there are absolutely no other cars in the vicinity, hence "no stopping needed". The rule is still there. And you get a warning for not following it.

Comment: @CareBear Traffic lights are simple. red, green, yellow, and no open for interpretation. Reviews are a little more complex in their rules, requirements etc.

Answer (score 8):

Just because you've visited the question doesn't mean the appropriate action on the post should change. Saying it needs no action makes no sense whatsoever from the perspective of the review. Further, this would open an abuse window where you could just open the question in a new tab, probably not even *look* at the new tab, and all buttons for the review item would now magically work. So no matter what you did, "you passed."

A better solution: If they choose to visit the question when it was an audit, the audit should just plain be voided. Show them a notice like "That was an audit. Since you visited the question, we went ahead and cancelled it for you."

I'm sure a lot of badge hunters would complain about that because they want their precious review count to increment for every possible thing, but the true reviewers that are in it *for reviewing* and not for the badge wouldn't mind losing a count on a review audit one little bit.

Comment: "Saying it needs no action makes no sense whatsoever from the perspective of the review" - The perspective of most reviews changes after looking at the question. I get the point - review in the review based on review data, but that's why I made this question - it could be improved. As for the "abuse window", I'm not saying "*viewing question means any button is then valid*" as flag/vote/other requirements would still be required first. If a user opened every review question in new tab and clicked "no action", they have as much chance of passing/failing audit as not opening the tab, as is now!

Comment: Do audits count as actual reviews toward badges? That would be odd. I sure hope they don't count against the daily review limit.

Comment: @CareBear Passed audits count towards your review totals as well as your daily review limit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm so skipping all audits from now on. The daily review limits are low enough already...