# Not allowed to flag deleted VLQ question during an audit

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12969861). I had attempted to flag as "Very Low Quality", but got a dialog saying "This answer has been deleted." Ok, I think, so I guess if I can't flag and it's already gone, well, no action is needed now? So I click that button and get "STOP!".

[There is a meta post about this already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274589/failed-audit-on-deleted-answer-with-no-action-needed-bit-unfair), but the poster there was asking for a different solution (and I agree with the answer there, would probably not work well).

After reading that, I understand why I should not have clicked "No Action Needed", even if the post was deleted. (I'm guessing I still could have downvoted or commented on the audit to pass - maybe my bad for not trying that first, but I figured since it was deleted, there was no reason to. Of course, I could have skipped, but at that point I was curious what the "right answer" was.)

**Proposal: Allow users to flag deleted posts in audit, as they would normally (not just for spam flags).**

That's what audits are supposed to check, right? I'm able to flag for spam on audits using now-deleted spam posts, so I don't see why audits of deleted posts from other flags should behave differently.

Comment: Very related: [Failed known-bad audit after flagging because I'm Done was not enabled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327580/failed-known-bad-audit-after-flagging-because-im-done-was-not-enabled).  Slightly different symptoms but same outcome.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but forcing yet another 3+ users to review crap in another queue is a massive waste of time and energy.  Be decisive.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm not sure what action you are suggesting by "be decisive"? At my rep, I can only downvote, comment, or flag.

Comment: @whrrgarbl Either skip, or flag as spam as you should.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't see the actual close reason, but it didn't seem like spam, just a low quality answer (which the comments on it also seem to indicate). So I didn't think flagging as spam would be appropriate. But more relevant to my question, does flagging a VLQ question as spam count to pass an audit? If so... weird, but if not, then I think there is still an issue.

Comment: There's something going wrong with flagging in audits.  Until it gets fixed, open the post in a new window to flag and skip the review.

Comment: @Will, thanks for the heads up. Is there a post somewhere about this? (just for reference / to watch for updates)

Comment: The link @ryanyuyu gave you is probably the best dupe target as of now.  It's annoying that there hasn't been any response from SE employees about this bug (that I've read).

Comment: Keep in mind that you have other options that you could take if you are unable to flag (because of bugs or because of no remaining flags). As I said in my answer to the Q @ryanyuyu links, I passed an audit, in spite of this bug, by attempting to leave a comment.